# Promises not getting resolved

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am running this asynchronous function in my React app -

```
const getMetaData = async (hashes: any) => {
    console.log({ hashes });
    try {
      const data = hashes.map(async (hash: any) => {
        const url = `http://localhost:3003/user/pinata/getmetadata/${hash}`;
        const metadata = await axios.get(url);
        return metadata.data.response;
      });
      console.log("data1", data);
      const metadata = await Promise.all(data);
      console.log('data2', metadata);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('getMetaData Error', error);
    }
  };
```

`console.log("data1", data)` gives me -

> data1 (12) [Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]

The problem here is after I do a `await Promise.all(data)` I don't get `data2` anywhere in the console. Maybe because the Promises are not even getting resolved?

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm , i think its caused by `const data = hashes.map(async (hash: any) => {`

Comment: Any specific reason? I'm getting `data1` though.

Comment: use `await Promise.all(hashes.map(async (hash: any) => {` instead

Comment: Tried that, I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Your code looks fine (but appears to be TypeScript, not JavaScript). Are you sure that all of your promises do resolve? That the server responds to all the requests? Try adding a timeout to axios maybe, and try logging each individual response so that you can see which ones you *don't* get.

Comment: @John OP already uses `await Promise.all`, they are just logging the intermediate array of promises.

Comment: @Bergi Oh yes you are right , did't see that.

Comment: Okay so here's the catch - while mapping through `hashes` I do not get a valid object response for every `hash`, as in some throw error.

Comment: I get desired response for some hashes but not for some

Comment: When an error is thrown, it should get to the `getMetaData Error` output, no? Or are you saying that the backend has an error and doesn't respond?

Comment: So, usually when I have this case, I will add logging on each response inside the `.map()` loop so you can see exactly what happens to each individual request (resolve or reject or neither).  This will tell you whether some request is rejecting and you're missing that or some request is never completing.  If you log appropriately, you can even see which request isn't completing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code works fine when using [SWAPI API](https://swapi.dev/) so it can be that the API you use does not deliver data appropriately. I run the below code to test. Here's a link to [codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-leaf-0985w?file=/src/index.js) to play around with it if you want.

```
import axios from "axios";

const data = ["people", "planets", "starships"];

const getMetaData = async (hashes) => {
  console.log({ hashes });
  try {
    const data = hashes.map(async (hash) => {
      const url = `https://swapi.dev/api/${hash}`;
      const metadata = await axios.get(url);
      return metadata.data.results;
    });
    console.log("data1", data);
    const metadata = await Promise.all(data);
    console.log("data2", metadata);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("getMetaData Error", error);
  }
};

getMetaData(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code, it appears the most likely situation is that one of the promises in the loop is not resolving or rejecting.  To confirm that, you can log every possible path with more local error handling so you can see exactly what happens to each request.  I also added a timeout to the request so you can definitely find out if it's just not giving a response, but you can also see that by just looking at the logging for begin and end of each request in the loop:

```
function delay(msg, t) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error(msg));
        }), t);
    });
}

const getMetaData = async (hashes: any) => {
    console.log({ hashes });
    try {
        const data = hashes.map(async (hash: any, index: number) => {
            try {
                console.log(`Request: ${index}, hash: ${hash}`);
                const url = `http://localhost:3003/user/pinata/getmetadata/${hash}`;
                const metadata = await axios.get(url);
                console.log(`Request: ${index}, result: ${metadata.data.response}`);
                return metadata.data.response;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`Request: ${index} error: `, e);
                throw e;
            }
        });
        console.log("data1", data);
        const metadata = await Promise.all(data.map((p: any, index: number) => {
            return Promise.race(p, delay(`Timeout on request #${index}`, 5000));
        });
        console.log('data2', metadata);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('getMetaData Error', error);
    }
};
```

FYI, I don't really know Typescript syntax so if I've made any Typescript mistakes here, you can hopefully see the general idea and fix the syntax.